# My tableView can't scroll smoothly

Tags: ios

I have a tableView A above a tableView B, A and B have the same hierarchy, A's height is half of B's height. Now the problem is that A can't scroll smoothly, can someone tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Keep it as light as possible. Ensure you are re-using cells in it and that no calculations are done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Cell is reused. When I clear B's data source and reloadData, A can scroll smoothly.